# Enabling libfdk_aac in ffmpeg installed with Homebrew

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, homebrew, codec

On macOs I always used to install or update ffmpeg through Homebrew. I use the libfdk_aac audio codec a lot so I always did this:

`brew reinstall ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac`

For some reason, since one or two brew updates, ffmpeg can no longer be installed with libfdk_aac.

When converting a video and using `-acodec libfdk_aac` which has been working fine for years, I now get:

> Unknown encoder 'libfdk_aac'

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Homebrew v2.0 dropped all of the extra options that are not explicitly enabled in each formulae. So the `--with` options no longer work if you use the core Homebrew formulae.

Instead you can use a third-party repository (or "tap") such as ​[homebrew-ffmpeg](https://github.com/homebrew-ffmpeg/homebrew-ffmpeg). This tap was created in response to the removal of the options from the core formulae.

Enable it then install `ffmpeg`:

```
brew tap homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg
brew install homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac
```

You can see a list of additional options with:

```
brew options homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg
```

It's recommended to install a recent build from the git master branch. You can do so with the `--HEAD` option:

```
brew install homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --HEAD
```

Comment: Wanted to mention that this method still works on Big Sur in 2021. Appreciated! Much easier than compiling on Windows.

Comment: Still works on macOS Ventura. I use this setup with beets to transcode select albums from my library and then transfer them to my iPhone with the Doppler app.

Comment: This errors out with: `Error: invalid option: --with-fdk-aac`

Comment: On M1 MacOS v13.5.2 it starts the make install and fails with - ld: building exports trie: duplicate symbol '_av_ac3_parse_header'.

Answer (score 8):

You could use **[`MacPorts`](https://trac.macports.org)** to install ffmpeg with `+nonfree` option.

In summary, you'll need to:

1. Install Xcode tools. Try `xcode-select --install`, or check [Apple's developer website](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).
2. Install MacPorts using the right [pkg file](https://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports.binary) for your MacOs release, or use one of the other options shown in the [MacPorts installation guide](https://guide.macports.org/#installing).
3. Install ffmpeg using MacPorts:

   `$ sudo port install ffmpeg +nonfree`

Which will ask:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for ffmpeg
The following dependencies will be installed: 
Xft2
XviD
aom
autoconf
autoconf-archive
automake
brotli
bzip2
cairo
cctools
curl-ca-bundle
dav1d
db48
expat
fontconfig
freetype
fribidi
gd2
gdbm
gdk-pixbuf2
gettext
gettext-runtime
gettext-tools-libs
giflib
glib2
gmake
gmp
gnutls
gobject-introspection
graphite2
graphviz
gts
harfbuzz
icu
jasper
jbigkit
lame
lcms2
libLASi
libass
libbluray
libde265
libedit
libfdk-aac
libffi
libheif
libiconv
libidn2
libjpeg-turbo
libmodplug
libnetpbm
libogg
libopus
libpixman
libpng
librsvg
libsdl2
libtasn1
libtextstyle
libtheora
libtool
libunistring
libvorbis
libvpx
libxml2
libxslt
lz4
m4
nasm
ncurses
nettle
openjpeg
openssl
openssl3
ossp-uuid
p11-kit
pango
pcre
perl5.28
perl5.30
pkgconfig
py39-beaker
py39-importlib-metadata
py39-mako
py39-markdown
py39-markupsafe
py39-setuptools
py39-zipp
python39
python3_select
python_select
rav1e
readline
shared-mime-info
soxr
speex
sqlite3
texinfo
tiff
urw-fonts
vala
webp
x264
x265
xorg-libX11
xorg-libXau
xorg-libXaw
xorg-libXdmcp
xorg-libXext
xorg-libXmu
xorg-libXt
xorg-libice
xorg-libpthread-stubs
xorg-libsm
xorg-libxcb
xorg-xcb-proto
xorg-xcb-util
xorg-xorgproto
xpm
xrender
xz
zimg
zlib
zstd
zvbi
Continue? [Y/n]: y
```

That will install all of those. The `libfdk-aac` codec will be built optimised for your machine, as well as `ffmpeg`. All of that takes some time.

Result:

```
$ ffmpeg -codecs | grep libfdk
AAC (Advanced Audio Coding) (decoders: aac aac_fixed aac_at libfdk_aac ) (encoders: aac aac_at libfdk_aac )
```

To see full codec list and supported formats:

```
$ ffmpeg -codecs
$ ffmpeg -formats
```

The other option would be to [compile it yourself](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/macOS) and choose whatever options you want.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be going with @llogan's ffmpeg tap solution for now, as it allows me to stick to Homebrew. But I had zero knowledge about MacPorts and it certainly looks useful, I may be using that more in the future as well, much appreciated for pointing that out!

Comment: Neither solution works for me on M1 MacOS v13.5. For macports - ld: warning: -single_module is obsolete
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lfreetype', '-liconv', '-lintl', '-lm', '-lvpx', '-lz'
ld: building exports trie: duplicate symbol '_av_add_i'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gmake: *** [ffbuild/library.mak:103: libavfilter/libavfilter.7.dylib] Error 1 - is the output.

Comment: @majorgear That error with MacPorts is recent. It used to work until a few days ago. I think someone just need to file a bug report on MacPorts Trac.

Comment: @huyz There was already on filed when I went to file one. No solution yet, but there was a comment that it may be an issue with clang. my brew config output says it's using clang-15.0.